# Docker コンテナ上の MySQLにホストOSから MySQL Workbenchで接続するには？

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

DockerでCentOS6を立ててその中に入り、MySQLをインストール
(決してMySQLのコンテナを立てていません。※そのため,Dockerfileとdocker-compose.ymlがない状態です)

このとき,ローカルの外部SQLWorkBenchから接続するにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

MySQLのコンテナをdockerで立てたものから,mysqlworkbenchとの接続の記事はたくさんあるのですが、上のケースは見当たりません。

firewallのポートを開ければつながるという記事も見て、iptablesをインストールしてport3306を開けたのですが、接続できませんでした。

ご存知の方ご教示お願いいたします。

**実行環境**
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
CentOS 6.10
MySQLWorkBench:8.0.18

---

```
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
17ab93fdf500        38596547d8dd        "/bin/bash --login"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   rails_main
```

とportは3000,3306を開けております。(よって、rails s して時,licalhost:3000でブラウザに写っています)

Docker内のCent0S6

```
>vi /etc/my.cnf

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
default-character-set=utf8
bind-address=127.0.0.1 # これを追加して、localhostからのを許可

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

```
vi /etc/hosts.allow

mysqld: ALL: allow  # 追加
```

```
>iptables --list  
(docker runの時に--cap-add=NET_ADMIN をつけ,firewallが起動できるようにしている)

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ftp-data 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:hbci 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:mysql  ## ここsqlを全て受け付ける

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain SERVICE (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

MySQL Workbench の接続は以下の通りです。

- Conection Method: Standard(TCP/IP)
- host:127.0.0.1
- port:3306
- name:root
- password:123456

これで接続を行っています。エラー内容は以下です

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

ちなみに

> select host,user ,password from mysql.user;

```
+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host         | User     | Password                                  |
+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost    | root     | *6BB4837EB74329105EE4568DDA7DC67ED2CA2AD9 |
| 0087ea0ee65d | root     | *6BB4837EB74329105EE4568DDA7DC67ED2CA2AD9 |
| 127.0.0.1    | root     | *6BB4837EB74329105EE4568DDA7DC67ED2CA2AD9 |
| localhost    |          |                                           |
| 0087ea0ee65d |          |                                           |
| %            | root     | *6BB4837EB74329105EE4568DDA7DC67ED2CA2AD9 |
+--------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
```

*6BB4837EB74329105EE4568DDA7DC67ED2CA2AD9 これが123456のhashされたものかな？

Comment: 「接続できませんでした」の部分で、実際に試した手順やエラーメッセージ等がもし表示されていたなら、それらの情報も質問文に含めてみてください。 / MySQL等のDBに接続するには一般的に、ネットワーク的につながっているかの他に「どのユーザーに対して」「接続元はどこか」を許可する必要があります。

Comment: 「CentOS6を立てて」だけでは情報が不十分なのでホストから見たコンテナのアドレスやポートのマッピングはどうなってますか？ わからなければ docker-run したときのコマンドを示してください。あるいは  docker-compose を使ってるならポートマッピングの yml ファイルがあると思うんですが ports: "3306:3306" のマッピングはできてますか？

Comment: 今回はymlファイルがありません。よって、docker run 時点でport 3000開けています。3306は開けれてないので、iptablesで開けたつもりなのですが、うまく行きません

Comment: docker run のオプションで全部指定しているのならオプションで -p 3306:3306指定したらダメなんでしょうか？

Comment: 複数port開けれるんですね。実際port開けて見たのですが、やはり接続できません

Comment: 念の為に確認しますが、Docker内の MySQL サーバは起動していますよね？

Comment: はい。起動しております